# Running a macro on change of target address

Tags: excel, vba, target

I have an If statement that runs on the change of a cell. This part works fine. However, when it runs the macro, for some reason it adds is about 40 extra lines. I'v used the breakpoint and discovered that the lines are added in after the the paste special. Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$AG$4" Then

Call CapEx_Copy_Paste_Delete

End If

End Sub

Sub CapEx_Copy_Paste_Delete()
'
' CapEx_Copy_Paste_Delete Macro
'

'
    Rows("11:11").Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B4:AG4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("AG4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B4:E4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("H4:I4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("L4:M4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("P4:Q4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("T4:U4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("X4:Y4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("Z4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AA4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AC4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AD4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B4").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `Select` for this kind of thing. Just call `Range("AG4").ClearContents`.

Comment: Also unrelated but you can combine ranges like so `Range("AG4", "B4:E4", "H4:I4").ClearContents` ect

Comment: @TimWilkinson, I couldn't get that to work...`Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`

Answer (score 3):

Does this work any better??:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$AG$4" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call CapEx_Copy_Paste_Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the neater version of your code. It's likely all that use of `Select` isn't helping your problems:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$AG$4" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call CapEx_Copy_Paste_Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub CapEx_Copy_Paste_Delete()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrRanges As Variant, v As Variant

    'set this as the worksheet you want to update
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'set this as the ranges you want to clear
    arrRanges = Array("AG4", "B4:E4", "H4:I4", "L4:M4", "P4:Q4", "T4:U4", "X4:Y4", "Z4")

    With ws
        .Rows("11:11").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        .Range("B4:AG4").Copy
        .Range("B11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        For Each v In arrRanges
            .Range(v).ClearContents
        Next v
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Updated** to include Gary's Student's suggestion - all credit goes to him for suggesting you disable events in your first sub